# Set 'focus' area in nvd3.js lineWithFocusChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm usuing the lineWithFocusChart.js model shown in the nvd3 examples shown here: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/examples.html

I want to be able to choose a specific x range for the graph to be focused on at load. I thought there would be a variable in chart that I could set to accomplish this.

Comment: you may be able to do something like `chart.brush.extent([x0,x1])` where `x0` and `x1` are the values you want the ends of the brush to start on. See https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js line 4908 to see that the brush is a `d3.svg.brush()`, and see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush to see what all you can do to a d3 brush.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose there's only one graph generated by nvd3 on the page:

```
chart = nv.graphs[0] // how to choose the graph by DOM id?
chart.brushExtent([10,20])
chart.update()
```

Thank @elsherbini's comment.

Comment: @pyCthon did you just try to call `nv.graphs` as a function? There's no such function invocation in my code, maybe you used `nv.graphs(0)` instead of `nv.graphs[0]`?

Comment: See this commit, https://github.com/tcotav/nvd3/commit/2edc2f7e0cdd9af7ab0f4bfbe47359b8f5fae31c, and my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999020/nvd3-accessing-a-chart-object

Comment: I deleted my old comment with the correct error now :). In the latest version of nvd3, `nv.graphs[0] -> TypeError: nv.graphs is undefined`

Comment: @yegle Is there any way to reset the brushExtent. Is there any function for reseting the focus that we selected in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided here no longer works with the newest version of NVD3. Instead, you can use the following when you create the chart:

```
  chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
    .options({
      brushExtent: [10000,490000]
    });
```

Or this after you've created it:

```
chart.brushExtent([10000,490000]);
```

See the documentation here: http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#lineWithFocusChart

Comment: Yeah, the "documentation" is very helpful: "No info for this option yet..."