# nvd3 + lineAndFocus + BrushExtent(access focus part that is clicked)

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm using the lineWithFocusChart.js model shown in the nvd3 examples shown here: http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html

I want to be able to get access to the values that the user selects in the `brushExtent` (slightly related see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197407/set-focus-area-in-nvd3-js-linewithfocuschart)) and then apply the focus to all other lineAndFocus charts.

I can do so for the line-chart part with this:

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementClick.customNameSpace', function(e) {
    console.log('click', e);
});
```

Is there something similar for the `brushExtent`?

*EDIT1*: I can control where it focuses using this code. Editing this example [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav)

```
chart.brushExtent([10,20])
chart.update()
```

*EDIT2*: This is what I am looking for, now I just need to put it all together,(i.e. draw the graph,listen for changes, then draw the graph with the changes...)

```
chart.dispatch.on('brush.update', function(b) { 
     console.log(b.extent[0], b.extent[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
chart.focus.dispatch.on('onBrush', function brushChanged(brushExtent) {
  otherCharts.forEach((chart) => chart.brushExtent(brushExtent));
});
```

I used a similar approach in my [lineWithFocusPlusSecondaryChart](https://github.com/COzero/nvd3/blob/feature/line-with-focus-plus-secondary/src/models/lineWithFocusPlusSecondaryChart.js#L631) model.