# Programmatically updating brush for LineWithFocusChart in Angular nvd3

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using the "LineWithFocusChart" in the Angular-nvd3 directives. The link to this directive is [here](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineWithFocusChart)

Now I need to change the focus of this chart programmatically rather than using the focus chart below. The answer for this issue is [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197407/set-focus-area-in-nvd3-js-linewithfocuschart) for the case of a simple nvd3 element. But I need to implement the same in the Angular directive of this chart.

I went through the docs and the issues on GitHub but to no avail. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch function for brush changes can be as follows:

```
function (e) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.tc.api.getScope().chart.brushExtent([e.extent[0], e.extent[1])
    }, 400)
}
```

$scope.tc.api represents the api for the other chart you wish to manipulate. It needs to be added to the chart directive as 'api="tc.api"' and declared in the controller before it can be manipulated.

The timeout is important because the directive needs a bit of time before it is loaded and its API gets activated.

**EDIT 1**
@ackuser has kindly set up a plunkr for the solution. http://plnkr.co/edit/0je3AsF0wdjkFWUyvl02?p=preview

Comment: Hi, Can you put a plnkr or jsfiddle with your solution...I think your question is really interesting

Comment: Sure. I actually don't know how to create a plnkr. I will put one up in 1-2 days.

Comment: @ Srujan Routhu .. Did you do this? I can create the plunkr for you if you need

Comment: Hey. It seems like you've done it all yourself. It's working exactly as expected, wherein the brush is auto adjusting after a little time. For more integrity, you can put the timeout function inside the callback function of the chart. This way, even if the chart api loads late the brush adjustment will execute

Comment: hehe ok so pls give me a point ;)....It because I have done it weeks ago so I didn't even remember I solved the problem

Comment: The plunkr doesn't work I think - would you be so kind to update it? I still don't get how you managed to make that work.

Comment: I updated the Plunkr so now it is working. I wasn't able to make it working without adding api.update() after the brush extent domain is changed.