# NVD3 accessing a chart object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

[In previous version's of `nvd3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197407/set-focus-area-in-nvd3-js-linewithfocuschart) you can do the following to access the chart/graph object.

`chart = nv.graphs[0];`

However in more recent versions this seems to have been removed:

```
nv.graphs -> undefined
nv.graphs[0] -> TypeError: nv.graphs is undefined
```

Is there an alternative way to access the chart elements as such?

```
chart = nv.graphs[0];
a = chart.brushExtent();
```

Here's a simple jsfiddle where you can see this in action as well,

http://jsfiddle.net/0m8jzetx/3/

[Here is the git issue where they remove it.](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/921)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a real answer, but have found something that may help accessing brushextents:
Rather than declaring chart as a global var, you can declare 2 global var for your extents, and update them when brush is updated, like so:

```
chart.dispatch.on('brush.update', function(b) {
  curve_focus_min = b.extent[0];
  curve_focus_max = b.extent[1];
});
```